# Cannot release OpenCV unsigned char matrix memory

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm working on a simple implementation of a caching system of OpenCV matrices. As part of it I'm  continuously loading and releasing `cv::Mat` objects by simply dereferencing it as:

```
cv::Mat mat = ...

mat = cv::Mat();
```

When dealing with matrices of type `CV_8U`, memory is not being released and returned to the OS while it does for matrices of type `CV_32F`.

A sample program reproducing the problem is:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf("-- Loading matrix of ones, press enter to continue...");

    getchar();

    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::ones(3000, 32, CV_8U);

    printf("-- Freeing memory, press enter to continue...");

    getchar();

    mat = cv::Mat();

    printf("-- Done, press enter to continue...");

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

When using type `CV_32F` memory is effectively released and returned to the OS while for type `CV_8U` it doesn't. To check if memory is free I'm simply looking at the System Process Monitor.

My system is an Ubuntu 12.10 over a x86_64 architecture. I'm using g++ 4.7.2 as compiler and OpenCV 2.4.6.1 bundled with ROS Groovy which I installed through the PPA.

Comment: There is a `release` member function to free a `cv::Mat`, can you try with this function?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I tried that already but I'm obtaining the same result. In addition I understand that cv::Mat uses a reference counting mechanism which automatically deallocates memory when the counter becomes zero which is precisely what cv::Mat::release does, decrement the reference counter to zero. This happens as well when it goes out of scope or in my case when I rewrite mat's header.

Comment: I'm on Win7_x64 with VS2010 and I can't reproduce the problem with OpenCV 2.4.8: the memory is correctly allocated then freed. Didn't tried with OpenCV 2.4.6. A solution maybe to recompile OpenCV for your platform ?

Comment: Also, did you try with a larger matrix size, such as 30000x1000, to make the allocation and releasing more obvious ?